# On solvable Lie algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $L$ be a Lie algebra over $k$.

We want to show that $L$ is solvable iff there is a chain $0=L_0 \subset L_1 \subset \dotsb \subset L_n=L $ such that $L_i$ is an ideal of $L_{i-1}$ and the factor algebra $L_i/L_{i-1}$ is abelian.

The $\implies$ part is easy, by showing that we can find such a chain, which is the chain of the derived subalgebras of $L$.

My question is how we can handle the converse?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: A quotient $K/I$ is abelian iff $[K,K]\subseteq I$.

Comment: Just look up a text on Lie algebras, e.g., [here](http://relaunch.hcm.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/perrin/chap7.pdf), Proposition $7.1.2$.

Comment: @Tobias Thank you for your comment. Now I see that using your hint, $L^{(1)} =[L_n,L_n] \subseteq L_{n-1}$ and inductively $L^{(n)} \subseteq L_0=\{0\}$ and hence it is solvable. Right?

Comment: @Diedrich Thank you for your comment. Can I ask you where did you find this nice set of notes?

Comment: I have known these notes before :) You can also find it in my own notes [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_28_lie_algebra_course.pdf).